# Flutter Geolocator 5.0.1 not working properly

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I'm having a problem with the flutter geolocator: ^5.0.1 dependencies. Bt it doesn't show the location also not showing any error. I have given permission in the manifest file also.

I'm using flutter stable version 1.22.6 and for this project compile SDK version is 29.

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`
```

Flutter Code for getting location:

```
                  String specificAddress;
                  try {
                    Position position = await Geolocator()
                        .getCurrentPosition(
                            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
                    List<Placemark> placeMarks = await Geolocator()
                        .placemarkFromCoordinates(
                            position.latitude, position.longitude);
                    Placemark mPlaceMark = placeMarks[0];

                    // String completeAddressInfo =
                    //     "${mPlaceMark.subThoroughfare} ${mPlaceMark.thoroughfare}, " +
                    //         "${mPlaceMark.subLocality} ${mPlaceMark.locality}, " +
                    //         "${mPlaceMark.subAdministrativeArea} ${mPlaceMark.administrativeArea}, " +
                    //         "${mPlaceMark.postalCode} ${mPlaceMark.country}, ";

                    specificAddress =
                        "${mPlaceMark.subLocality}, ${mPlaceMark.locality}, ${mPlaceMark.country}";

                    locationTextEditingController.text = specificAddress;
                    setState(() {
                      _location = specificAddress;
                    });
                  } catch (e) {
                    _showSnackbar(e.toString());
                  }`
```

**Error** > when I press the "get my location button" it shows nothing....

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The geolocator package has a newer version, try updating to that.

Comment: I have tried the latest version (6.1.7) but still the same problem.

Comment: Can you try printing `position` after calling the async function

Comment: yes, I have tried it. but it printed nothing.

Comment: Stop the current build, run `flutter clean` and build again

Comment: I have done all those but they are not working.

Comment: @cdaiga what problem are you having?

Comment: @faithomotoso finally noticed I could not get my exact location when I am inside a building, so I got my exact location when I went out.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to you use either `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` but not both in the same AndroidManifest.xml file.